# $f : \mathbb{N} → \mathbb{R}$, f(x)= $\sqrt{x+4}$ - what is the range?

Tags: linear-algebra, functions

For a revision task that I'm confused whether a solution is formal enough.

$f : \mathbb{N} → \mathbb{R}$

$f(x) = \sqrt{x+4}$

What is the range of this function?

Given $f(0) = \sqrt{4} = 2$ my initial guess is to say $\{\sqrt{x+4} \in \mathbb{N}\}$ or something like,

$X = \{y \in \mathbb{R} : y \in I\}$

$I = \{\sqrt{x+4} \in \mathbb{N}\}$

Meaning the range is any real number, such that it's equal to the square root of any natural number (non-negative integer) + 4, however I'm not sure if this is a formal enough way of defining the range.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: You should write $\{\sqrt{x+4} : x \in \mathbb N \}$.

Comment: Thanks @Desperado

Answer (score 1):

The function maps from natural numbers to real number. Since it is increasing with increase in x, your lowest closed number should be f(1)=√5, and not f(0) since 0 is not a natural number. Your range becomes [√5, infinity)

Comment: Many people define $0$ to be a natural number; in my experience the two definitions are about equally common.